# Imagecord function is not getting accessed after clicking the submit button in form

Tags: php

```
</head>
<BODY>

<?php
        function Aftersubmit()
    {
        $myname = $_POST['myname'];
        if(isset($myname)){
        echo ($myname);

        }

    }
        function Imagecord()
    {
        if(isset($xcoord) && isset($ycoord)){
        $xcoord=$_POST["myimage_x"];
        $ycoord=$_POST["myimage_y"];
        echo ("X=".$xcoord);
        echo ("Y=".$ycoord);
        }
    }


    if(isset($_POST['submitbutton'])){
        Aftersubmit();
        Imagecord();
    }

?>
```

Imagecord() function is not getting accessed, like the Aftersubmit button in PHP.
I want to click on image and after submit it should display the coordinates.

Comment: where are $xcoord and $ycoord being set?

Comment: Did you bother checking if $_POST['submitbutton'] actually exists?

Comment: Shouldn't it be -> `if(isset($_POST["myimage_x"]) && isset($_POST["myimage_y"])){ $xcoord=$_POST["myimage_x"]; $ycoord=$_POST["myimage_y"]; ... }`?

Comment: From below discussion under answer posted by me about myimage_x not getting posted in $_POST, the problem is with your form submission and not your php code. Can you post your html form and the relevant form submitting code if any?

Answer (score 0):

Modified function

```
function Imagecord()
    {
        if(isset($_POST["myimage_x"]) && isset($_POST["myimage_y"])){
        $xcoord=$_POST["myimage_x"];
        $ycoord=$_POST["myimage_y"];
        echo ("X=".$xcoord);
        echo ("Y=".$ycoord);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. I have edited the function, but still it is not working. If loop is not working.

Comment: @user3407447 do a var_dump($_POST); before the if statement to check whether the expected $_POST['myimage_x'] and $_POST['myimage_x'] are being posted or not

Comment: I checked, the values myimage_x and myimage_y are not getting posted.

Comment: @user3407447 Then the problem is with your form submission and not your php code. Can you post your html form and the relevant form submitting code if any?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>


</head>
<BODY>

<?php
        function Aftersubmit()
    {
        $myname = $_POST['myname'];
        if(isset($myname)){
        echo ($myname);

        }

    }
        function Imagecord()
    {

        $xcoord=$_POST['myimage_x'];
        $ycoord=$_POST['myimage_y'];
        echo "X=".$xcoord;
        echo "Y=".$ycoord;


    }


    if(isset($_POST['submitbutton'])){
        Aftersubmit();
        Imagecord();
    }

?>

<script>
        function myJavascriptFunction(){
            alert ("hello World");
        }

</script>

    <form   action= "forms.php" enctype = "multipart/form-data" method="post">
        first name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mary"><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value= "clan"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mychoices[]" value="choice1" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mychoices[]" value="choice2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="mychoices[]" value="choice3">
        <select name="myselection">
        <option value="selection1" selected>Option1</option>
        <option value="selection2">Option2</option>
        <option value="selection3">Option3</option>
        </select>
        <select name="myselections[]" size="3" multiple>
        <option value="choice1" selected >Choice1</option>
        <option value="choice2" selected>choice2</option>
        <option value="choice3">choice3</option>
        </select>
        <textarea name="mytextarea" rows="10" cols="40">
        Welcome to the web developement world.
        </textarea>
        <input type="password" name="mypassword"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="myname" value = "myvalue"/>
        <input type="file" name="text"  size="100"/>
        <input type="button" value="My Button" onclick="myJavascriptFunction()"/>
        <input type="reset" value="reset form"/>
        <input type="image" name="myimage" src="desert.jpg" height="42" width="42">
        <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Submit Form"/>

    </form>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```